# replacing content in a page with varnish + regex

Tags: regex, caching, webserver, varnish, varnish-vcl

If I want my varnish cache server to replace content inside a page (ie: change the class on a div) from the backend before serving or storing the page (vcl_fetch?), how can this be done?

I would like to use simple regex to perform the replacement as I imagine it is supported natively in varnish.

Answer (score 6):

Modifying response body is not natively supported by Varnish. You need a Varnish module (vmod) for this.

Aivars Kalvans has [libvmod-rewrite](https://github.com/aivarsk/libvmod-rewrite), which does exactly what you are looking for. However the vmod is a proof of concept and according to Aivars it is not ready for production use. You can use it as a starting point in any case.

If you are using Apache, you can use [mod_ext_filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html) to modify response body. Here's an example from mod_ext_filters documentation. Since you can pass the response body to any external command, it is very easy to do the necessary modifications to the content.

```
# mod_ext_filter directive to define a filter which
# replaces text in the response
#
ExtFilterDefine fixtext mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/bin/sed s/verdana/arial/g"

<Location />
# core directive to cause the fixtext filter to
# be run on output
SetOutputFilter fixtext
</Location>
```

Comment: Ended up just writing my own passthrough before it gets to varnish.  I'll have a look at libvmod-rewrite though.  Thanks.

Comment: Regarding `mod_ext_filters` I think maybe [mod_substitute](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html) might be an even better fit for the usecase, if apache is an option