# nginx reverse proxying multiple application requesting similar assets

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have several applications located at:

```
http://www.foo.com:80
http://www.bar.com:42
http://www.baz.com:1337
```

that I am attempting to reverse proxy with one nginx machine. the issue I have right now is that these applications are requesting files that are identical in name, but not identical in content:

```
location /bootstrap.css {
 proxy_pass http://www.foo.com:80/bootstrap.css;
}

location /bootstrap.css {
 proxy_pass http://www.bar.com:42/bootstrap.css;
}

location /baz {
 proxy_pass http://www.baz.com:1337;
}

location /foo {
 proxy_pass http://www.foo.com:80/;
}
```

is it possible for me to re-write all responses coming from a particular application server to point to it's application subfolder?

ex: redirect

```
http://www.foo.com:80/*
```

to

```
/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup something like:

```
location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://www.foo.com:80;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

However, your application foo might need to know about this. See this [post](http://www.htpcguides.com/configure-sickrage-reverse-proxy-nginx/) for example.

**EDIT:**

Nginx might be able to do what you want by using [sub_filter from ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html)

Try the example in: [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818182/modify-html-response-not-headers) and [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542282/how-do-i-rewrite-urls-in-a-proxy-response-in-nginx)

Comment: The issue is that the html emitted by www.foo.com has absolute references to say -- /bootstrap.css, rather than /foo/bootstrap.css

How do I get the response from www.foo.com to be /foo/bootstrap.css or to get the request for /bootstrap.css to forward to /foo/bootstrap.css

Comment: I don´t know if nginx can do this alone. I believe this is application´s foo responsibility. Look the [post](http://www.htpcguides.com/configure-sickrage-reverse-proxy-nginx/) and see that author´s explicit tells to configure application (Sickrage in this example) to be aware it will be called from inside a directory (/sickrage in the example).
Are your application self contained or served by an Apache server or other http server? I don´t know if it is possible to rewrite responses in Apache or any other http server.

Comment: Actually it is possible as shown in the EDIT section above. I hope it helps you.